# READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission Not asking in Android 13

Tags: java, android, android-studio

android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE]

am try to read the Files(pdf and docs) from the storage before that device not asking the permission.

```
String[] PERMISSIONS = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

private void requestPermission() {

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_REQUEST_GALLERY_CODE);

 }
```

suggest me any changes for android SDK 33 new updates.

Comment: If the user is not involved using this code then just try to create a file in external storage. You will soon see if the permission is obtained. First let your app create a file. It does not make sense trying to read a file of another app.

Answer (score 2):

Don't need ask permission for this. They do not exist for Android 13+ devices anymore. You have WRITE permission by default in all public directories on external storage. You can access all files without any permission.

Answer (score 0):

You can no longer use `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in Android 11+ if u want to access directories other than your app's private folder.

You can read more about it here -> https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage

If u just need to read PDF's and images from the device, u don't need the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission. Just ask for `READ_STORAGE_PERMISSION` and u can read files as long as they are not in other app's private folders.

Comment: `You can no longer use WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in Android 11+` No. You have to use it if you want to create files in external storage.

Comment: `as long as they are not in other app's private folders.` As long as they are not created/owned by another app.

Comment: READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission also not asking from android 13